# How to start Datanode? (Cannot find start-dfs.sh script)

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

We are setting up automated deployments on a headless system: so using the GUI is not an option here.

Where is start-dfs.sh script for hdfs in Hortonworks Data Platform? CDH / cloudera packages those files under the hadoop/sbin directory. However when we search for those scripts under HDP they are not found:

```
$ pwd
/usr/hdp/current
```

Which scripts exist in HDP ?

```
[stack@s1-639016 current]$ find -L . -name \*.sh
./hadoop-hdfs-client/sbin/refresh-namenodes.sh
./hadoop-hdfs-client/sbin/distribute-exclude.sh
./hadoop-hdfs-datanode/sbin/refresh-namenodes.sh
./hadoop-hdfs-datanode/sbin/distribute-exclude.sh
./hadoop-hdfs-nfs3/sbin/refresh-namenodes.sh
./hadoop-hdfs-nfs3/sbin/distribute-exclude.sh
./hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode/sbin/refresh-namenodes.sh
./hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode/sbin/distribute-exclude.sh
./hadoop-hdfs-namenode/sbin/refresh-namenodes.sh
./hadoop-hdfs-namenode/sbin/distribute-exclude.sh
./hadoop-hdfs-journalnode/sbin/refresh-namenodes.sh
./hadoop-hdfs-journalnode/sbin/distribute-exclude.sh
./hadoop-hdfs-portmap/sbin/refresh-namenodes.sh
./hadoop-hdfs-portmap/sbin/distribute-exclude.sh
./hadoop-client/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh
./hadoop-client/sbin/slaves.sh
./hadoop-client/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh
./hadoop-client/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
./hadoop-client/etc/hadoop/kms-env.sh
./hadoop-client/etc/hadoop/mapred-env.sh
./hadoop-client/conf/hadoop-env.sh
./hadoop-client/conf/kms-env.sh
./hadoop-client/conf/mapred-env.sh
./hadoop-client/libexec/kms-config.sh
./hadoop-client/libexec/init-hdfs.sh
./hadoop-client/libexec/hadoop-layout.sh
./hadoop-client/libexec/hadoop-config.sh
./hadoop-client/libexec/hdfs-config.sh
./zookeeper-client/conf/zookeeper-env.sh
./zookeeper-client/bin/zkCli.sh
./zookeeper-client/bin/zkCleanup.sh
./zookeeper-client/bin/zkServer-initialize.sh
./zookeeper-client/bin/zkEnv.sh
./zookeeper-client/bin/zkServer.sh
```

Notice: there are ZERO start/stop sh scripts..

In particular I am interested in the **start-dfs.sh** script that starts the namenode(s) , journalnode, and datanodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to start DataNode

`su - hdfs -c "/usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config /etc/hadoop/conf start datanode";`

[Github - Hortonworks Start Scripts](https://github.com/hortonworks/hortonworks-sandbox/blob/master/start_scripts/start.sh)

**Update**

Decided to hunt for it myself.

1. Spun up a single node with Ambari, installed HDP 2.2 (a), HDP 2.3 (b)
2. `sudo find / -name \*.sh | grep start`
3. Found

   (a)  `/usr/hdp/2.2.8.0-3150/hadoop/src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/bin/s‌​tart-dfs.sh`

   Weird that it doesn't exist in `/usr/hdp/current`, which should be symlinked.

   (b) `/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/10/mapreduce.tar.gz/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh`

Comment: The link you provide is to a start-all script for a sandbox that is (a) not included in the hdp distro (b) inadequate for HA and (c) includes mapred stuff (I only want dfs) .

Comment: 1) `./hadoop-client/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh` 2) Your question did not specify HA

Comment: hadoop-daemon.sh is not a start script for dfs but only for a single hdfs process.  I am already using it manually - the point of this question is to get a sanctioned" and self contained script to start hdfs.

Comment: The answer to this question really depends how you installed Hadoop, but [the wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop) says those scripts are located in `$HADOOP_INSTALL/hadoop/bin`

Comment: They are not and have not been since 1.0. They were moved around 2012 to sbin. But now they are not even in sbin.

Comment: Wow, nice sleuthing!  I had done `find . -name \*.sh` under /usr/hdp/current and did not find it. Awarding well deserved correct answer.

Comment: actually I don't have it there.. I am on ambari 2.3.0 .. but that would be unlikely to make the difference..  But in any case your answer would still likely be correct for many users so I will leave it accepted.  I'm out of luck, but that's not your fault.

Comment: I think you mean HDP 2.3, not Ambari, and sorry to hear that. I'm doing a 2.3 install right now to see if that changes anything.

Comment: See update. It looks like the sources are simply being downloaded by the automated installer because I can't just run `start-dfs.sh` on its own without adding it to the PATH.

Comment: Wow again: that path to the script underneath `/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/10/mapreduce.tar.gz/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh` is *way* not easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to administer your hadoop cluster would be via the administrator panel. Since you are working on Hotronworks distribution, it makes more sense for you to use Ambari instead.

Comment: We are setting up automated deployments on a headless system - so the GUI is not an option.  I will update the OP.